# dynamic row column in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Simply I can fetch an array with `foreach` and create a table as:

```
<?php foreach ($trainee as $key => $value): ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?= $value->TraineeID ?></td>
 </tr> 
<?php endforeach?>
```

But when numbers of table column not fixed then I can not create the columns and its value.

data array:

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TraineeID] => 30012
            [Inv.1] => 720
            [Inv.2] => 2100
            [Inv.3] => 3540
            [Inv.4] => 4920
            [Inv.5] => 6300
            [Inv.6] => 7800
            [Inv.7] => 8700
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TraineeID] => 30033
            [Inv.1] => 720
            [Inv.2] => 2100
            [Inv.3] => 3540
            [Inv.4] => 4920
            [Inv.5] => 6300
            [Inv.6] => 7800
            [Inv.7] => 8700
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TraineeID] => 30037
            [Inv.1] => 720
            [Inv.2] => 2100
            [Inv.3] => 3540
            [Inv.4] => 4920
            [Inv.5] => 6300
            [Inv.6] => 7800
            [Inv.7] => 8700
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [TraineeID] => 30038
            [Inv.1] => 720
            [Inv.2] => 2100
            [Inv.3] => 3540
            [Inv.4] => 4920
            [Inv.5] => 6300
            [Inv.6] => 7800
            [Inv.7] => 8700
        )
)
```

desired Output like below:

```
TraineeID   Inv.1   Inv.2   Inv.3   Inv.4   Inv.5   Inv.6   Inv.7
30012        720    2100    3540    4920    6300    7800    8700
30033        720    2100    3540    4920    6300    7800    8700
30037        720    2100    3540    4920    6300    7800    8700
30038        720    2100    3540    4920    6300    7800    8700
```

Comment: so if Inv.2 not exist in one array element then entire element's (here 4) `Inv.2` will empty?

Comment: no no that will never empty, The situation is its always start from `Inv.1` to `inv.2, 3 4 5` simultaneously. sometimes it goes to `inv7` or `inv.8` or less but never empty in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php 
    foreach ($trainee as $traine):
        echo "<tr>";
        $tds = get_object_vars($traine);
        foreach ($tds as $property => $value) {
            echo sprintf("<td>%s</td>",$traine->{$property});
        }
        echo "</tr> ";
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Excellent treatment, but column header not showing here, could you, please help a bit more?

Comment: what do you mean column header

Comment: I mean top row for column header like: TraineeID, Inv.1, Inv.2 and so on

Comment: you can write hard coded header row before trainee loops

Comment: But I really don't get, all rows and columns come with this loop then why it skips the column name?

Comment: please let me know if one of your result row can be excluded Inv.1 or Inv.2 and so

Comment: do you know urdu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126791/discussion-between-mir-abzal-ali-and-syed-arif-iqbal).

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Use this

```
<?php foreach ($trainee as $key => $value): ?>
<tr>
 <td><?= $value->TraineeID ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.1 ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.2 ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.3 ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.4 ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.5 ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.6 ?></td>
 <td><?= $value->Inv.7 ?></td>
</tr> 
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: numbers of the column not static here, so this will not work

Comment: Then count the array and loop it again.